# this.props.createNewBook is not a function. How to add new prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Header.js

```
 class header extends React.component {
{
  render(
<CreateBook bookType= { createBookType } closeModal= { this.closeModal } />
)
}
}
```

CreateBook.js

```
  class CreateBook extends React.Compoent {
      showResult() {
        const errors = this.validate();
        if (errors.length === 0) {
          this.props.createNewBook(JSON.stringify(this.state.model));
        } else {
          this.setState({
            errorList: errors,
          });
        }
      }


  render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    return (
.
.
.
<Button id= "save" onClick= {() => this.showResult()
  }> Save </Button >
}
CreateBook.propTypes = {
  createNewBook: PropTypes.func,
  bookType: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  closeModal: PropTypes.func,
};
```

Now I created a container which has

```
    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
      createNewBook: (data) => dispatch(createBookAction(data)),
    });

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(CreateBook);
```

In the above code, I can't get createNewBook prop value . So, I cant call dipatch function.

When i am trying to get log, I only get bookType and closeModal.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: FYI, javascript is case sensitive, and it requires not only the case to be correct, but the names of variables and functions as well

Comment: The above code is a sample one. I followed case properly in original code. Still I am getting the same issue.

Comment: Did you import `createBookAction` ?

Comment: Assuming you really have `onClick= {() => this.showResult()}` in your actual code, there should be no problem with binding. However, if you had `onClick={this.showResult}`, then there WILL be a problem.

Comment: Could you console.log your `this.props` and see what's inside?

Comment: Please include all code including export/import statements. Side note; Javascript is case-sensitive. Cannot imagine this doesn't throw an error `REact.component`. Check your console for errors.

Comment: console.log(this.props) gives me {bookType: "newbook", closeModal: ƒ}

Answer (score 0):

To use `this` in `showResult`, you need to bind it in the constructor:

```
this.showResult = this.showResult.bind(this)
```